# Angular Apollo client returning bad request

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo-client

I'm practicing `Graphql` & `Apollo Client` for Angular.

I'm having issues in creating queries from client side.

I've successfully created graphql queries in backend.

Below is my GQL Query which returns data and it's displayed in `Playground`

**GQL Query**

```
{
  getData {
    data {
      type
    }
}
```

**My Client side code,**

**Service.ts**

```
export class ContentService {
  constructor(    private apollo: Apollo,
    ) {
      this.getContent();
    }

   async getContent(): Promise<any> {
    const response: any = await this.apollo.query({query: getContentQuery}).toPromise();
    return console.log(response);
  }
}
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong over here.

Unable to find the solutions answer. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is your query in client side:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const getContentQuery = gql`
  query getContent {
    metadata {
      type
    }
  }
```

The `query getContent` is the name you are giving to your query in your code, but it's not the actual "query name" to send to your backend.
I think you have to do something like:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const getContentQuery = gql`
  query getContent {
    getContent {
      metadata {
        type
      }
    }
  }
```